# SQL_BIG_SELECTS, refining my query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I'm using an HTML select input, with multiple selections enabled, and I'm looking over the selected options and trying to process my SQL ... however, I get a warning from SQL telling me that if my select statement is right, I should use "SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS = 1" since the JOINs are over the limit?

Here's my query:

```
"
        SELECT wposts.*, wpostmeta.* 
        FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta2, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta3 
        WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id 
            AND wposts.ID = wpostmeta2.post_id 
            AND wposts.ID = wpostmeta3.post_id 
            AND wpostmeta.meta_key = 'listing_subtype' 
                AND wpostmeta.meta_value = '$search_home_type' 
            AND wpostmeta2.meta_key = 'map_area' 
                AND ";

                $count = 0;
                foreach ($params['search_map_area'] as $map_area) :
                    if ( $count != 0 ) :
                        $querystr .= "OR ";
                    endif;
                    $querystr .= "wpostmeta2.meta_value = '$map_area' ";
                    $count++;
                endforeach;

    $querystr .= "AND wpostmeta3.meta_key = 'price_current' 
                AND wpostmeta3.meta_value BETWEEN $search_price_min AND $search_price_max 
            AND wposts.post_status = 'publish' 
            AND wposts.post_type = 'vreb_property' 
        ORDER BY wposts.post_date DESC 
        LIMIT 0, 20
        ";
```

Is there a better way to query this? It's the multiple `OR wpostmeta2.meta_value = '$map_area'` that seems to cause my script to timeout ...

Comment: If your select is that big I'd worry about the resulting query being really slow. What does the query look like after the code has run?

Comment: It actually doesn't run ... it times out now. Even with `SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS = 1`

Answer (score 0):

```
    FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, 
        INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta ON wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id
        INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta2 ON wposts.ID = wpostmeta2.post_id
        INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta3 ON wposts.ID = wpostmeta3.post_id 
    WHERE ...
```

Using JOIN ... ON is probably preferred over having all of the ID relations in your WHERE class.

---

You should really be using parameterized queries, so you don't open yourself up to SQL injection because it doesn't seem like your properly escaping any of the strings your using. http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

But if your working on a private/internal app and security be damned ...

```
            $temp = "'" . implode("','", $params['search_map_area']) . "'";
            if($temp != "''")
                $querystr .= "wpostmeta2.meta_value IN ($temp)";
            else
                $querystr .= " 1=1 ";
```

Using the IN keyword instead of multiple "OR col = 'val'" is also preferred.